# Unity Quiz Game

Tags: c#, unity2.0

my new question is about the quiz I'm making in unity, how can I make it so that if the question is answered the first time it skips two duplicates, and if it is answered the second time it skips only one duplicate, I have a scriptable object and there is my list of questions, to make it easier for you to understand, it looks like this:

What is C# ?
What is C# ?
What is C# ?
What is Java ?
What is Java ?
What is Java ?
....... Next Questions

and I have a code that skips duplicates based on the correct answers, but it doesn't work the way I need it, because it needs to work the same way for each question, not to give me it constantly skips 2 then 1 2 then 1, but for each question as I said, it is answered correctly, it skips two duplicates, if it is answered correctly from the second attempt, it skips one duplicate, I hope you understand me, this is part of the code that serves that function.
Public bool Odgovor control the answers,based on the counter of correct answers it will skip 2 then 1 2 then one, and for me it should go the way I explained to you

```
public StatusIgre StatusIgre { get { return statusIgre; } }

    public void PokreniIgru(int index)
    {
        brojacBodova = 0;
        trenutnoVreme = ogranicenjeVremena;
        ostatakZivota = 3;
        pitanja = new List<Pitanje>();




        for (int i = 0; i < sadrzajPitanja[index].pitanja.Count; i++)
        {
            pitanja.Add(sadrzajPitanja[index].pitanja[i]);

        }

        IzaberiPitanje();
        statusIgre = StatusIgre.IgraSe;
    }


    void IzaberiPitanje()
    {
        if (pitanja.Count > 0)
        {
            if (preskociDuplikate > 0)
            {
                // Skip the specified number of questions
                for (int i = 0; i < preskociDuplikate; i++)
                {
                    pitanja.RemoveAt(0);
                }
                preskociDuplikate = 0; // Reset the skip counter
            }
            izabranoPitanje = pitanja[0];
            kvizUI.PostaviPitanje(izabranoPitanje);
            pitanja.RemoveAt(0);
        }
        else
        {
            statusIgre = StatusIgre.Sledece;
            kvizUI.KrajIgre.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (statusIgre == StatusIgre.IgraSe)
        {
            trenutnoVreme -= Time.deltaTime;
            PodesiVreme(trenutnoVreme);
        }
    }

    private void PodesiVreme(float vrednost)
    {
        TimeSpan vreme = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(vrednost);

        kvizUI.VremeTekst.text = "Vreme:" + vreme.ToString("mm':'ss");

        if (trenutnoVreme <= 0)
        {
            statusIgre = StatusIgre.Sledece;
            kvizUI.KrajIgre.SetActive(true);
        }
    }

    public bool Odgovor(string odgovoreno)



    {
        bool tacanOdgovor = false;

        if (odgovoreno == izabranoPitanje.tacanOdgovor)
        {
            tacanOdgovor = true;
            brojacBodova += 50;
            kvizUI.BodoviTekst.text = "Bodovi:" + brojacBodova;
            // Brojac tacnih odgovora za trenutno pitanje
            izabranoPitanje.tacniOdgovori++;
            

            if (izabranoPitanje.tacniOdgovori == 1)
            {
                // Preskace sledeca dva pitanja ako je odgovor tacan iz prvog pokusaja
                preskociDuplikate = 2;
            }
            else if (izabranoPitanje.tacniOdgovori == 2)
            {
                // Preskace sledeci pitanje ako je odgovor tacan iz drugog pokusaja
                preskociDuplikate = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                // Resetuje brojac tacnih odgovora i preskace duplikate
                izabranoPitanje.tacniOdgovori = 0;
                preskociDuplikate = 0;
                
            }

        }
        else
        {
            ostatakZivota--;
            kvizUI.OduzmiZivot(ostatakZivota);

            if (ostatakZivota <= 0)
            {

                statusIgre = StatusIgre.Sledece;
                kvizUI.KrajIgre.SetActive(true);
            }

            izabranoPitanje.tacniOdgovori = 0;
            preskociDuplikate = 0;
        }

        if (preskociDuplikate > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < preskociDuplikate; i++)
            {
                IzaberiPitanje();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            IzaberiPitanje();
        }



        return tacanOdgovor;
    }
```

I hope I managed to explain to you what I need.I know that the code should be in English, but I started my work in Serbian, because it is for a graduate thesis and I wanted it to be done entirely in Serbian.

Comment: Did I understand correctly? There are 3 attempts for each question, if the answer is correct, display the next one, otherwise continue to display the current one until the attempts are exhausted.

Comment: Why not just ask question 1, then if the answer is wrong ask it again and keep a counter of wrong answers? This seems unnecessarily complex.

Comment: My first langauge isn't English, but I always name my variables and methods in English, it makes it a lot easier to get help in an international world.

Comment: Shingo yes, each question has two more duplicates because each one has an addendum, the first one is only the text of the question, if he answers incorrectly he gets the same text with a picture, if he answers incorrectly the third time he gets the text and video, and if he answers correctly the first time then he goes to the next question, skips two duplicates, if it answers from second try , it skips one duplicate.

Comment: Palle Due of course I know, but since this will be my first game and I'm making it for my graduation, I wanted it to be in Serbian, if I continue to do this, the others will always be in English

Comment: I'm making an associative quiz, so I need that when I have three attempts, if the answer is incorrect, the first attempt is only the text, the second attempt is the text and image, the third attempt is the text and video or sound, and if the answer is correct there is no need to go through duplicates, because actually duplicates they give an association to answer the question more easily, I make a quiz for children in primary schools from 4 to 8 grades

Answer (score 0):

1. Store the number of correct attempts for each question in a separate data structure, such as a dictionary.
2. Update the number of correct attempts for each question accordingly.
3. Modify the IzaberiPitanje() function to skip duplicates based on the number of correct attempts for each question.

First, create a dictionary to store the number of correct attempts for each question:

```cs
private Dictionary<Pitanje, int> correctAttempts;
Initialize the dictionary in the PokreniIgru function:

correctAttempts = new Dictionary<Pitanje, int>();
for (int i = 0; i < sadrzajPitanja[index].pitanja.Count; i++)
{
    pitanja.Add(sadrzajPitanja[index].pitanja[i]);
    correctAttempts[sadrzajPitanja[index].pitanja[i]] = 0;
}
```

Update the number of correct attempts in the Odgovor function (or wherever you're checking for correct answers):

```cs
public void Odgovor(bool isCorrect, Pitanje currentQuestion)
{
    if (isCorrect)
    {
        correctAttempts[currentQuestion]++;
    }
    // ... (Other logic for handling correct/incorrect answers)
}
```

Finally, modify the IzaberiPitanje() function to skip duplicates based on the number of correct attempts for each question:

```cs
public void IzaberiPitanje()
{
    Pitanje selectedQuestion = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < pitanja.Count; i++)
    {
        int skipCount = correctAttempts[pitanja[i]] == 1 ? 1 : 2;

        if (i + skipCount < pitanja.Count && pitanja[i].Equals(pitanja[i + skipCount]))
        {
            i += skipCount;
        }
        else
        {
            selectedQuestion = pitanja[i];
            break;
        }
    }

    if (selectedQuestion != null)
    {
        // ... (Set the selected question and update the UI)
    }
    else
    {
        // ... (Handle the case when there are no more questions)
    }
}
```